# finding the average of a range of rows by column data

Tags: python, pandas, average, rows

In working on this project, I have to get averages of sertain subsets of data in the main data file (my main csv that I'm reading in from has about 500 entries)

```
df = 
Score   Name    Rating
 2         A    5
 3         A    5
 5         A    4
 4         A    5
 3         B    4
 3         B    4
 5         B    5
 2         C    3
 4         C    3
 4         C    4
....
```

I've parsed the set to make sure that all the names are uppercase and that all the scores and ratings are numeric
this is what I'm starting off with, but I'm still a beginner and struglling though...

```
    ds = ds.sort_values(by=['Name'])
    counts = ds["Name"].value_counts()

    names = []
    ratings = []
    avg = []
    for i in range(0, hotel_count(filename)):
        avg[i] = pd.rolling_mean(pd.Series(range(counts[i]), window=2)
```

I'm looking for output that resembles

```
Name   AverageScore 
A        3.5
B        3.6
C        2.6
```

Comment: I think you want `df.groupby('Name', as_index=False)['Score'].mean()` or `df.groupby('Name', as_index=False).agg(AverageScore=('Score', 'mean'))`. Though the value for C is off from your provided sample set. The average of [2,4,4] is 3.33333. Unless you actually need the rolling window of size 2, in which case can you [edit] your expected output to outline how the rolling average is supposed to be considered?

Comment: Use `df.groupby('Name', as_index=False)['Score'].mean().rename(columns={'Score': 'AverageScore'})`